# Convert random number to integer in Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have using spring schedule job and would like randomly delay the job by input `initialDelayString = "#{T(java.lang.Math).random() * 10000 }"`. I can generate the random number but the value is a `long` value (e.g. 4242.423422432)

How can I convert the value to `integer` using SpEL?

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10000)`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the current value is not a `long`, but rather a `double` as per return type of [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()).

Also, you can always convert a `Double` to `int` by calling `.intValue()` on it, e.g.:

```
    Double someValue = 2.56;
    int nearlyTheSame = someValue.intValue();
    System.out.println(nearlyTheSame);
```

So your Spring expression might be:

```
  #{(T(java.lang.Math).random() * 10000).intValue()}
```